# While porting project from 64bit to 32 bit : float changed to long double gives error for %f

Tags: c, printf, 32bit-64bit, porting

As while porting 64 bit project to 32 bit project for making range compatible changed:

```
typedef float float_t;
```

to

```
typedef long double float_t;
```

All goes perfect but error is coming in all printf specifier for %f. I don't want to change to %Le in whole code.

Please suggest any generic solution so it is campatible to both 32 bit and 64 bit system in c language.

Comment: Please tag your question with C or C++ depending on what language you're working with.

Comment: Why are you changing from float to long double anyway ? This is not necessary or meaningful when porting between 32 and 64 bit architectures.

Answer (score 3):

You are going to have to use a #define for the format string for the float / long double, or use a special formatting function

Comment: Following the lead of `inttypes.h`, you could define `PRIf64` to either `"f"` or `"Lf"`.  Usage: `printf( "value=%9.2" PRIf64 "\n");`

Answer (score 0):

You did not sepcify what language you are using.  In C++ `std::cout` is preferred over `printf` and it will give you type-correct formatting.

If you are using C, you could define a macro based on the platform for both the type of the floating point variables and the formatting string for `printf`